# How to use images data from database and display in the my home activity like olx in android?

Tags: android

I want to know how to display the images that has been stored in the database in the home activity in my application.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow Please read this

Answer (score 0):

just store them in regular file system ,create a directory

```
File file=new File(getabsolutepath()+"/image/")
```

this path doesn't change so just  store the image name in a database.

you can also store images in database using blob https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

but it is not a good practice

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.